# how to solve Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ts-loader'?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, frontend, webpack-dev-server

ERROR in index
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ts-loader' in '/home/asd123456/ic-projects/token'
resolve 'ts-loader' in '/home/asd123456/ic-projects/token'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: /home/asd123456/ic-projects/token/package.json (relative path: .)
resolve as module
looking for modules in /home/asd123456/ic-projects/token/node_modules
single file module
using description file: /home/asd123456/ic-projects/token/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/ts-loader)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfuO9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install`. If that does not work, then remove the `node_modules` directory and repeat the previous command.

Comment: thanks you so much! I got answer already https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-module-not-found-cant-resolve-ts-loader

Comment: no problem. if the answer you used matches my answer then you should still mark my answer as "answer" for future reference.